# CakePHP Manipulate the return of a find() using conditions on a 2nd level deep model association

Tags: php, cakephp, data-binding, model, cakephp-2.0

I have tried and tried and tried and I do not know what I am doing wrong. I have a simple scenario where I have Project *hasMany* Tag and Tag *belongsTo* Project.

When I display a list of all current projects, I want to show a list of tags with each. The tags are fetched perfectly fine with the hasMany relationship as it is, but I want the find condition to be conditioned when a user clicks on any tag, only returning projects that contain the clicked tag.

I understand that I cannot manipulate a hasMany binding directly in the conditions option of my find, and I also understand that I need to make use of the *unbindModel()* and *bindModel()* methods to set up a temporary *hasOne* relationship where *Project hasOne Tag*. I assumed I would need to follow the process of:

- Unbinding the Project hasMany Tag
- Create a binding of Project hasOne Tag
- I would then be able to manipulate the Tag.name field in my conditions option.

**Here is my relationship in the Project.php model file:**

```
     public $hasMany = array(
        'Link' => array(
            'className' => 'Link',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            'dependent' => false,
        ),
        'Pledge' => array(
            'className' => 'Pledge',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            'dependent' => false,
        ),
        'ProjectPost' => array(
            'className' => 'ProjectPost',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            'dependent' => false,
        ),
        'Tag' => array(
            'className' => 'Tag',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            'dependent' => false,
        )
    );
```

**Then in my Tag.php model file:**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Project' => array(
        'className' => 'Project',
        'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
    )
);
```

All models make use of the containable behaviour. Now, inside my ProjectsController.php file I am modifying the bindings to achieve a hasOne relationship so that I can manipulate the results based on the Tag.name value:

// I am unbinding the hasMany tag relationship
$this->Project->unbindModel( array('hasMany' => array('Tag')) );

```
    // I am setting up a hasOne relationship where Project hasOne Tag
    $this->Project->bindModel(array(
    'hasOne' => array(
        'MyTag' => array(
            'className' => 'Tag',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array('MyTag.project_id = Project.id')
        )
    )
    ));
```

**I then issue a simple find command (with no filter on tags yet):**

```
$projects = $this->Project->find(
        'all',
            array(
                'contain' => array(
                    'MyTag',
                    'User.id'
                ),
                //'conditions' => $filters ? $filters : NULL,
                'fields' => array(
                    'Project.id', 'Project.name', 'Project.description' 
                ),
            )
        );
```

Now I only have ONE project record in the database, but it has five tags. What is happening is that it is returning the ONE project, but 5 times, here is a pr() of the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Project] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Test Project 01
                    [description] => Donec enim lacus
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Project] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Test Project 01
                    [description] => Donec enim lacus
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Project] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Test Project 01
                    [description] => Donec enim lacus
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Project] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Test Project 01
                    [description] => Donec enim lacus
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Project] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Test Project 01
                    [description] => Donec enim lacus
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

The strangest part of all is that if I DO enable a filter on the *MyTag.name* field (note I use *MyTag* because I changed the class name during binding), it works as expected:

```
$projects = $this->Project->find(
        'all',
            array(
                'contain' => array(
                    'MyTag',
                    'User.id'
                ),
                'conditions' => array('MyTag.name' => 'NGO'),
                'fields' => array(
                    'Project.id', 'Project.name', 'Project.description' 
                ),
            )
        );
```

The above returns just a single result. *What is going on?* How can I prevent this duplication on the initial (non filtered) load?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think your should take a look at [hasAndBelongsToMany](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm) relations.
This is how I setup tag behaviour.
Good luck!

**EDIT**

You would be able to do

```
$this->Project->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('Project.id' => $projectId),
    'recursive' => 1
));

// returns
Array [
    Project => Array [...],
    Tag => Array [all associated tags]
]
```

And

```
$this->Project->Tag->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('Tag.id' => $tagId),
    'recursive' => 1
));

// returns
Array [
    Tag => Array [...],
    Project => Array [all associated projects]
]
```

Is that not what you want?

Comment: But this will still not solve the issue of being able to manipulate the results of projects based on their tags will it? As far as I am aware, the only associations that can be manipulated from within the find() query are hasOne associations, or is this incorrect?

Comment: I edited my post, if that doesn't help i think i misunderstood your question... good luck!

Comment: @ issem danny - I suppose I could return the projects as associations to a certain model, but Ideally I wanted to be working only with the Project model, because there is a difference in the data structure for showing all projects from the Project model, as opposed to showing all projects as an association to Tag for example, make sense? so I'd essentially be having to work with two very different sets of data, just to filter by a tag. If that's the only solution, then so be it, I will have to make it work. Many thanks for your suggestions. I could have used this approach with the hasMany too

Comment: I think dealing with the difference in data structure is way less complicated then trying to create HABTM behavior without a third database table... but then again haven't got much experience with the containable behavior and lot of relations so might be wrong... Good luck!